# Multislots in calendar for a custom field in views Drupal

Tags: 7, views, entities, datetime

My table (from another database) is exposed as entity in Drupal 7, so I can create [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) from it.

I have two fields in the database (`start_date` and `end_date`). How can I make views treat these custom date fields (from custom entity) as a Drupal date field in such a way that the "Calendar view" shows it in multi slots ?